ISS Cupola window coatings
The Space Station has a viewing port, called the Cupola. It has 7 windows. Anybody know if there are coatings on these windows?

@JamesK Honestly, we should have a migration path to Space SE and vice versa at this point.

very related: How do modern "space windows" protect from dangerous UV? Is it simply the type of glass, or are there coatings or filters also? and slightly related: How (the heck) do you replace a space station window in orbit?

There are at least

an Antireflective Coating
a Conductive Antireflective Coating, and
a Scratch-Resistant Antireflective Coating,

per Spacecraft Window Design from a Thermal Perspective by Cheyn L. Worn. I assume the info on the windows is sourced both from "Engineering of Windows for the International Space Station, L.R. Estes & K.S. Edelstein" and contact with Estes and others in JSC-ES2 and ES3 per the last slide in the deck.
I've reproduced the image showing where the coatings are on the various panes from the slide deck here.  Note that the deck doesn't elaborate on what the coatings are; I assume the paper elaborates, but I haven't been able to find it free.  I assume the measurements are in inches; the comments of this answer are not a place to suggest that they should be in other units.
Anecdotally, I have heard through the grapevine that astronauts have requested that the scratch panes be removed so they can actually get good views/photos out of the windows, to limited success, but I couldn't tell you how many years ago that was, if it was true at the time, or if it has held true.


I suspect the astronauts’ dislike of the inner window is due to the dispersion (low Abbe number) of the Lexan (polycarbonate) anti-spalling layer. For instance, the Abbe number of borosilicate glass is 65 and Fused Silica is 67 while polycarbonate is 30. Despite being described as “high optical quality”, many people reject polycarbonate eyeglass lenses because the high dispersion (low Abbe number) causes fringing around edges of objects.

@Woody yes, it must be something like that.  I remember something akin to "we spent millions of dollars making optically-perfect windows and then we put this in front of them"

@Woody under what conditions dispersion actually "causes fringing around edges of objects"? All the time? Substantially off-axis? Out of focus? Can you find a realistic image shot with a simple point-and-shoot camera (not a telescope) through a polycarbonate window that shows fringing strong enough to be noticed visually?

@uhoh ...Good point. Dispersion (different refractive index for different wavelengths) causes chromatic aberration in focused images, but I cannot understand how a flat plate would cause fringing, even off-axis. Other possibilities: Microscratches due to surface softness, birefringence, lower transparency than glass, higher scattering than glass. Stars present the perfect opportunity to test optical materials: point sources against a perfectly black background. I’ll post comparison pictures when the clouds clear.

The paper you mention doesn't contain any details about the coatings. It just talks about how microscopic scratches can from propagating cracks in the glass,  so the outer unpressurized debris pane was added to protect the pressure pane from getting scratched by debris.

this document from NASA mentions Cerium Oxide as a coating used on the windows, but doesn't go into detail.

The space between the two "pressure panes" is marked as "vented to space". I would have expected "unvented" or something similar. Am I missing something, or do I need to ask a new question?

@TomCarpenter thanks very much; I note that the document you refer to mentions cerium oxide being used on windows but doesn't seem to directly link them to the cupola windows. Though it's a pretty likely hit

@NL_Derek "why is the space between the pressure panes vented to space" seems like a valid question to me.  I think that's just the standard arrangement and the vent to space for that area can be sealed, but it's desirable to not have the additional air-glass interface from both an optical standpoint and repairability of the outer pressure pane standpoint.

We see reflections in images of the new Moon - e.g. iss071e160736.NEF - we see a 'rainbow' and we see a reflection both out onto the sky near the Moon and inwards over the lunar disc. They seem to be of similar intensity so we do no think they are sequential orders of reflections. [link][https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipN97WXhns-9jFyTnU_T5_UmpTmOXDnNTFL9RIEf]

Here is (hopefully the link to the image of the Moon with the 'rainbows') link

@PeterThejll I can't see either one of those, just a google error message and a cartoon of a broken robot. I usually open a temporary post (additional answer or new question) import the image to Stack Exchange, copy the new link, then delete the text without posting it. Then everyone is guaranteed to be able to see it even if it disappears from the original source.

@ErinAnne optically, air-glass and vacuum-glass interfaces are essentially the same

@ChrisH until you hit the dew point ;-)

Answer: YES. there are anti-reflection and anti-scratch coatings.
According to http://wsn.spaceflight.esa.int/docs/201107/Annex1-ESA-ISS-CC-AO-Climate-Change.pdf :

Each window consists of three panes of high quality borosilicate
glass, plus an protective inner pane. The inner pane can be removed to
permit high quality observations through the windows. The windows
transmit primarily in the visible and short wave Infrared wavelength
range.
Glass pane material & thickness
• Pressure panes (Primary & Redundant) : – anti-reflection coated
fused silica glass – 1.45 in. (3.68 cm) thick for the top window, 1.0
in. (2.54 cm) thick for the side windows
• Scratch panes: – borosilicate glass (SCHOTT BK7) – 0.44 in. (1.12
cm) thick for both top and side windows – Anti-spall film on the cabin
side of the glass, treated with scratch resistant anti reflection
coating – Conductive anti-reflection coating (ITO) acting as heater on
space-oriented glass surface – The removal of this pane can be
considered in exceptional cases to improve window optical performance
• Debris panes : – anti-reflection coated fused silica glass – 0.37
in. (0.94 cm) thick for both top and side windows

The reference also includes specifications for optical properties and transmittance requirements

interesting that the first paragraph in your quote seems to contradict the follow-on bullets in your source and the cross-section in my source.  +1 though

@ErinAnne ... right you are ! I suspect it is a typo. Fused silica glass has very high resistance to thermal shock (as well as excellent optical quality). Borosilicate outshines silica in resistance to mechanical shock resistance.
